# Normal distribution test integer/discrete data

Tags: r, integer, normal-distribution, anova

I want to conduct ANOVA in R and have to check for normal distribution before. Therefore I could use `shapiro.test(y)` or `ad.test(y)`. However this is not possible for discrete/integer values. I tested the following:

```
y <- rnorm(100, 2.5, 1)
ad.test(y) # p-value = 0.864
shapiro.test(y) # p-value = 0.9052
```

And discrete values:

```
y <- round(y)
ad.test(y) # p-value = 1.021e-08
shapiro.test(y) # p-value = 3.628e-05
```

Is there a way to test integer data in R Studio for normal distribution?

Best regards

Comment: The results you see are exactly what one should see. Normal data that has been rounded really isn't normal. Especially if you have a low standard deviation.

Comment: If you do `y <- 1.001*round(y)`  instead of `y <- round(y)` you will also badly fail the test for normality, so the result has nothing to do with data type.

Comment: Yes I know "integer" might be imprecisely formulated. I mean discrete values of ordinal scales (1-2-3-4). As far as I know ANOVA is appropriate way to analyse this kind of (ordinal scaled) data too. But how can I test this ANOVA assumption for given data set in R?

Comment: Discrete data is not normal distributed. No need to test that. What is this data? Often, disrete data is count data, which can be analyzed without assuming normal distribution, e.g., using Poisson regression or similar GLMs.

Comment: Please try to avoid cross posting the same question to multiple sites. Choose the most appropriate one. I you choose wrong you can always flag for migration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using tests for normality on discrete data (although it might be fundamentally misguided to do so, especially if the data is categorical rather than genuinely numerical). As @Dason points out, rounding normal data changes its distribution, in a way that is especially noticeable when the standard deviation is small. To see the effect of the standard deviation, repeat your experiment this way:

```
y <- rnorm(100, 250, 10)
ad.test(y) # p-value = 0.7949
y <- round(y)
ad.test(y) # p-value = 0.6395
```

If you run such a test before ANOVA and you get very low p-values, then perhaps ANOVA isn't appropriate. ANOVA is fairly robust, but there is a limit to how far you can depart from the assumptions. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5680/143190) for a nice discussion. You might need to run a non-parametric test such as [Kruskal-Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) instead. Perhaps you could post a question which describes your actual use-case on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since the question really involves statistical methodology rather than R per se.

Comment: First, thank you for you answer. I thought it might be a R-related question if there is a function in R that handles this issue. I already read your first link before. I've got the impression that a lot of researchers just ignore the assumptions if they don't really fit. I'll post my specific question there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Agent49 The question you asked was reasonable and clearly R-related. The question that perhaps you *should* have asked isn't really R-related and is better answered by an expert in statistics. You are right that a lot of researchers ignore assumptions. It is good that you don't want to be one of those researchers. Tangentially -- the book "Statistics Done Wrong" is a wonderful read which shows some of the problems that can happen when researchers use methods that they don't really understand.

Comment: I completely agree and yes I am sometimes a bit too accurate to solve problems fastly... I definitively should take a look into that book. Thank you. :)

Comment: @John These data are not rounded -- they're simply discrete categorical; ie plainly not normal.

Comment: @Glen_b The nature of the data wasn't given in the question itself, although it emerged in a subsequent comment which didn't exist when I was writing this answer. In any event, it is still true that there is no intrinsic problem in testing such data for normality, even if the conclusion of the test is a forgone conclusion.

Comment: I mentioned it because I figured the additional information might lead you to qualify your answer. [If someone is using a goodness of fit test to assess normality when they know it's not normal, failure to reject is simply a failure to tell you what you know to be true. Why would that be helpful? "Doesn't reject" doesn't imply "is sufficiently close to normal for some purpose"]

Comment: @Glen_b Good point. I added a remark about the pointlessness of testing categorical data for normality.

Comment: @John Coleman I agree that it is pointless to test categorical data. I thought normal distribution is just not possible for nominal (e.g. "male", "female") data which trivially makes sense but it seems that this is also the case for ordinal data (e.g. "1-2-3-4"). Nevertheless it's more a statistical than a programming problem and I'll have to read about it more deeply.

Comment: @Agent49 Ordinal data is admittedly somewhere between purely nominal and straight numerical. The problem is that it typically doesn't make sense to do arithmetic on such numbers and tests for normality rely on arithmetic (e.g. averaging the numbers to get an estimate for their mean). There are some cases where it makes some sense to ask if they are approximately normal (e.g. if the categories are age brackets) though in such cases the ordinal values would be related to background numerical variables.